# What is "SAP on Oracle"

Tags: oracle, sap

OK, total newb question.

What is "SAP on Oracle", exactly.  [This link](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/sdn/ora) is talking about how SAP can run on Oracle (I think).

I'm not understanding how this is working.

My understanding:

- SAP is a company that provides ERP
- Oracle is a database system.

I thought they were competitors!  So, is SAP on Oracle running the ERP system on Oracle?  What is running here and what would a DBA be supporting in this scenario?  (Or would this even be DBA territory?)

I'm asking because I've applied for a job that prefers "SAP" experience and I ran into this "SAP on Oracle" in my googling.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[SAP AG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAP_AG) (Often just called SAP) is a company which has a product called SAP ERP (Enterprise Resource Planning).  Since Oracle also makes ERP software they are indeed competitors.  In fact they are the top two ERP vendors.

SAP can be used with quite a few different database systems, but according to one source I found Oracle is dominant comprising around 80% of SAP systems.  Oracle recently won a law suit against SAP for intellectual-property theft. (http://news.cnet.com/8301-1001_3-20029601-92.html#ixzz1CWy7UiKR)

Here is some [SAP on Oracle documentation](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/0d/d2f6b74a0c11d182b80000e829fbfe/frameset.htm).

It does seem like a strange scenario for a product to depend so heavily on a competitors product, but it is not unheard of.  To some extent this pattern exists for Oracle with their database product running on Microsoft Windows servers.

Comment: As far as the why is concerned: Oracle's ERP solution is essentially the JD Edwards ERP application because Oracle purchased PeopleSoft in 2005 which was owning JD Edwards. At that time SAP was already the biggest(?) ERP vendor and was supporting Oracle. So the situation is "home-grown" by Oracle, by buying a competitor to SAP.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ERP_software_packages lists JD Edwards EnterpriseOne, JD Edwards World, Oracle e-Business Suite, and PeopleSoft as separate sets of ERP software available from Oracle.  JD Edwards was purchased by PeopleSoft and the PeopleSoft was purchased by Oracle, yet each ERP package is still available as a separate product from Oracle.  In September of 2010 Oracle launched Fusion apps their migration path for people using PeopleSoft or JD Edwards, however http://www.oracle.com/us/products/applications/index.html still lists them each as separate products available.